# Ubuntu boot problems on Dell XPS 13 after replacement of motherboard

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Background: I recently had a spill that damaged my Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition, which was preinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04.

My motherboard has been replaced. I removed the SSD before repair; now I've put it in again and I can't boot anymore - I don't even get to grub; I just get a "No bootable device found." error and can go no further.

I hit F12 on startup and try booting from the UEFI partition. When I do this, I get an error from initramfs: "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system".

I tried setting up a USB with Boot Repair. I can boot up with this, and from there I can see that the correct partitions are still there and the Ubuntu partition still looks good on /dev/sda4.

dev/sda1 is the EFI system partition. I can mount /dev/sda4 just fine.

But how do I get the system to boot correctly again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if there is any BIOS option for the hard drives like `AHCI` or `IDE` and try the one or the other (maybe the new motherboard has different setting than the one you had when you installed Ubuntu and this will make the disk unbootable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Insert Ubuntu Live-Dvd/Usb.

Ensure the bios boot order is set to read the media first and start the computer

Select Ubuntu Live / `Try mode`.

Click on purple Ubuntu search button - enter `gnome-terminal` and click on its icon

In a terminal run:

```
exec sudo -i
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
chroot /mnt
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
```

Comment: When I try to chroot, it fails. It looks like I can't run /mnt/bin/bash - I get "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" when I try. I'm running the 64-bit Ubuntu Studio image from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/16.04/release/.

"file /mnt/bin/bash" shows this is an x86-64 executable. This is on an i5-5200U. Am I using the wrong Ubuntu version, or is this something else?

Comment: Try to run: chroot /mnt  /usr/bin/bash

Comment: I did - I still get the "Exec format error" when I try to do that as well.